# Function definition of Clojure built-ins: def vs defn

Tags: function, clojure, definition

Why are some (many) of Clojure's built-in functions defined using `def`, not `defn`?

I know that `defn` is a shortcut for `def`, but I'm wondering if there's some other reason such as efficiency/readability/style considerations/bootstrapping.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Read further down in [clojure/core.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/ba930d95fc3a4a78c5bd6756ea483c9dac681618/src/clj/clojure/core.clj) - `defn` doesn't exist yet at the top, because that file is building the language as it goes. After several hundred lines, `defn` [is written](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/ba930d95fc3a4a78c5bd6756ea483c9dac681618/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L263), and functions after that are defined with `defn`.

Comment: genius. the incremental building of the language is one of the many things that makes the Clojure source such an interesting read!